# Compute $\mathbb{E}(e^{t \max_{i}X_{i}})$

Tags: probability, inequality, moment-generating-functions

Let $X_{i}$~$Bin(n, p)$.

I know that the moment-generating function of a Binomial distribution is defined as :

$$ \mathbb{E}(e^{t X_{i}}) =(1-p+pe^{t})^{n} $$

But what about $\mathbb{E}(e^{t \max_{i}X_{i}})$ ? Do we need any independence between the variables to compute it ? Or is there any upper bound for it ?

Comment: On the contrary. It is much more easy to compute under ultimate *dependency*: $X_1=\cdots=X_k$.

Comment: The ultimate dependency is a strong assumption. Using this could be considered as an upper bound? or not necessary..I think

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{E}(e^{t\max_{i}X_{i}})=\sum_{k=0}^{n}e^{tk}\mathbb{P}(\max_{i}X_{i}=k).$ Under independence of the $X_{i},$ $1\leq i\leq m$, $\mathbb{P}(\max_{i}X_{i}=k)=\mathbb{P}(X_{1}\leq k)^{m}-\mathbb{P}(X_{1}\leq k-1)^{m},$ for $k=1,\ldots,n,$ and $\mathbb{P}(\max_{i}X_{i}=0)=\mathbb{P}(X_{1}=0)^{m}.$ So \begin{align*}\mathbb{E}(e^{t\max_{i}X_{i}})&=\mathbb{P}(X_{1}=0)^{m}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{tk}(\mathbb{P}(X_{1}\leq k)^{m}-\mathbb{P}(X_{1}\leq k-1)^{m})\\
&=(1-e^{t})\mathbb{P}(X_{1}=0)^{m}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}e^{tk}(1-e^{t})\mathbb{P}(X_{1}\leq k)^{m}+e^{tn}\\
&=(1-e^{t})\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{tk}\mathbb{P}(X_{1}\leq k)^{m}+e^{tn}.\end{align*}

This last expression could conceivably be used for computation.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't have any information saying that the vaiables are independent.

Comment: @LinaHam you can replace the expressions in this answer like $P(X_1\le k)^m$ with $P(X_1\le k, X_2\le k, \ldots, X_m\le k)$

Comment: In that case, you need to try to get a handle on $\mathbb{P}(\max_{i}X_{i}=k)$ for the collection of $X_{i}$ you're considering and use the first formula in my answer. Probably, you'll have to compute these probabilities using the joint pmf of the $X_{i},$ which conceivably you have access to (otherwise I think it's somewhat hopeless).

Comment: Yes, I will try this. I am wondering if there is any upper bound for this in function of $X_{i}$

Comment: Not without some information about the possible dependencies. For example, if $p=1/2,$ then $X_{2}=n-X_{1}$ also has a Binomial($n,p$) distribution if $X_{1}$ does, but $\max_{i=1,2}X_{i}\geq n/2$ for any value of $X_{1}.$ Many strange behaviors can appear depending on the dependencies.